# How to specify possible data types for a template function

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to make a function that takes two data types, each of which I know will be a descendent of a `drawable` class, meaning my function depends on some of `drawable`'s functions. However because it is a template function I can't do this.

**How can I make it so I can use these descendant class functions? Or make it so only descendents of `drawable` are accepted?**

here's the beginning of my function. GetPositionY is drawable's function.

```
template<typename T, typename T2>
bool CheckCollision(T* obj1, T2* obj2){
    obj1->GetPositionY;
```

Comment: It's usual to call it a *derived* class, not a *descendant*.

Comment: `bool CheckCollision(drawable* obj1, drawable* obj2);` ?

Comment: you should elaborate on what it is you 'can't do', the wide range of answer you have so far is because we can't tell if you have just misunderstood how templates work or are actually trying to do something more tricky

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `CheckCollision()` function shall require the client to pass an object that provides `GetPosition()` methods. That's what you do when calling `obj1->GetPositionX()` inside your template. There's no reason to force it to pass a `drawable` object.

Comment: This is called duck typing, and its a pretty big part of the appeal of C++'s template system.

Answer (score 2):

By using a combination of :

boost::is_base_of from Boost.TypeTraits
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_base_of.html

and boost::enable_if

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/utility/enable_if.html

```
template<typename T, typename T2>
typename boost::enable_if< boost::is_base_of< Drawable, T1>, bool>::type 
CheckCollision(T* obj1, T2* obj2)
{
  obj1->GetPositionY(); // ... whatever
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unlike C#, which will assume the lowest common denominator and requires the use of the "where" clause to resolve this, C++ takes the path of not checking the template type usage until the method is actually invoked with a specific type.  So only types that provide the required methods will compile.  e.g.

```
template<typename T, typename T2>
bool CheckCollision(T* obj1, T2* obj2) {
        obj1->GetPositionY;
}

class A
{
        public:
                int GetPositionY;
                A() { };
};

class B
{
        public:
                B() { };
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        A a;
        B b;

        // this compiles just fine
        CheckCollision(&a, &a);
        // this line will not compile, "error: 'class B' has no member named 'GetPositionY'"
        // CheckCollision(&b, &b);

        return 0;
}
```

There is a discussion about this difference with C# and C++ generics [here.](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/01/13/c.net-little-wonders-constraining-generics-with-where-clause.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Add a trait structure for your `drawable` class that you can use to test whether the types instantiated in the template are the correct types.  This would look something like

```
//default for any data-type
template<typename T>
struct drawable_type
{
    enum { drawable = 0 };
};

//specialization for a drawable class
template<>
struct drawable_type<drawable>
{
    enum { drawable = 1 };
};

template<typename T, typename T2>
bool CheckCollision(T* obj1, T2* obj2) 
{ 
    if (drawable_type<T>::drawable && drawable_type<T2>::drawable)
    {
        //do something
    }
    else
        return false; 
}
```

Now if the types past aren't drawable, your function will simply return false, otherwise you can continue to test and see if a collision occurred.